# Mongodb sort with case insensitive manner

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am struct very hard at one project in nodejs(express) with mongodb as database. When i get all data using sort() it returns data in wrong manner, so is there way to get it properly format as i am expecting as below:
If we have three record in DB:

```
---------------------
id  | Name |  aga
---------------------
1   | atul | 21
---------------------
2   | Bhavik | 22
---------------------
3   | Jay | 25
```

What i am getting at present is:

2,3,1 series data

What i expect is to come is:
1,2,3

It means is to ignore the case while sorting is it possible without adding new column.

Comment: did you try `sort({name:1})` or may be replacing -1 for your required output?

Comment: This will not work when we have more records as mongodb sort in Capital Letters first and then second letters, means it does not check for case insensitivity

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use [**`collation`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) here with `locale: "en"`

```
db.collection.find({}).collation({ locale: "en" }).sort({ name: 1 })
```

So for the below document

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Bhavik" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Jay" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "atul" }
```

You will get

```
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "atul" }
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Bhavik" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Jay" }
```

Comment: Actually i also have to use populate on same query then it is possible ?
Below is my actual code that i am using : (I have tried with collection but it gives error) 

let properties = await Property.find({'status':{$in:status}}).populate({path: 'user',
      model: 'User',select: 'first_name last_name mail contact_number'}).populate({path: 'category',
      model: 'Category',select: 'category_name id'}).sort(sortClause).skip(skip).limit(perpage).exec();

Comment: getting error like : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: server 192.168.137.152:27017 does not support collation

My OS: Linux Ubuntu17

Comment: mongoose and mongodb version?

Comment: Mongoose 5.4 
and output of mongo --version is as below :

db version v3.2.20
git version: a7a144f40b70bfe290906eb33ff2714933544af8
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1604
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64

Comment: you need to update your mongodb version to 3.4 or above to use collation

Answer (score 1):

Create the collection with a default collation by this way you can order by any property with case insensitive.

```js
db.createCollection("collection_name", { 
    collation: { 
        locale: 'en_US', strength: 2 
    } 
})

db.getCollection('collection_name')
    .find({})
    .sort( { 'property_name': -1 } )
```

More info: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `collation: { locale: 'en' }` directly in the `options` parameter of the [`find`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#find) method:

```
db.collection.find({ ...query }, {
  sort: ...,
  limit: ...,
  collation: { locale: 'en' }
}
```

Comment: This is for [node-mongodb native](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html) driver. But not for mongoose. **:-)**