# MongoDB: Sort UTF-8 strings

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have this aggregate and i was sorting a field (`_id.name`) with lowerCase and **UTF-8**, but i can't sort the strings like "á" or "Á" or anything like. How can i sort utf-8 and lowerCase strings?

**Aggregate:**

```
Schedule.aggregate([{
      $match: {
        store: req.body.store,
        scheduleStart: {
          $lte: start,
          $gte: req.body.period
        },
        status: {
          $in: resultStatus
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          name: "$employee.name",
          id: "$employee.id"
        },
        totalValue: {
          $sum: "$value"
        },
        totalServices: {
          $sum: 1
        },
        totalComission: {
          $sum: "$comissionValue"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      '$addFields': {
        'ticket': {
          '$divide': ['$totalValue', '$totalServices']
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        "_id.name": 1
        }
    },
    {
      $skip: req.body.limit * req.body.page
    }
```

**Edit**

Now I using collation like this:

```
 Schedule.aggregate([{
     ...     
    {
      $sort: {
        "_id.name": 1
      }
    },
    {
      $skip: req.body.limit * req.body.page
    }

  ], { "collation": { "locale": "pt" }}).exec((error, response) => {
    if (error) res.status(500).send({
      error,
      code: 0,
      message: langs[req.query.lang].somethingWentWrong
    });
```

**The ERROR:**
MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]

Comment: This will work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015712/mongodb-sort-with-case-insensitive-manner/52015956#52015956

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet how can i pass  the collation and locale inside my query?

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`collation`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) here with `locale: "en"`

With aggregation you can do something like this (mongodb)

```
Schedule.aggregate([{ "$sort": { "_id.name": 1 }}], { "collation": { "locale": "en" }})
```

With mongoose you can use [**collation**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collation) inside your schema

```
var schema = new Schema({
  name: String
}, { collation: { locale: 'en' })

Schedule.aggregate([{ "$sort": { "_id.name": 1 }}]).exec((error, response) => {
  console.log(response)
})
```

Comment: I edited my answer to show the error and my code now, the error is "MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]"

Comment: @Matheus I have updated my answer please have a look

Comment: Here, doesn't work because i'm using 'pt' (Portuguese) and the sorting is not working correctly, and I don't know why

Comment: Could you edit your question with the sample collection.