# exact match with case insensitive in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to match the username in the collection.

```
User.findOne({ username: {$regex: new RegExp('^' + req.body.username, 'i')} }).select('_id').exec(function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({  "status": 0, "message": "Something went wrong" });
                } else {
                    if (user) {
                        res.json({ "status": 0, "message": "This username is already taken." });
                    } else {
                        res.json({ "status": 1, "message": "Username is valid" });
                    }
                }
            });
```

I have already record with username "vikash1" in the collection. I want to check if the username exists or not.
When I enter "Vikash2" then above query will return "username already exists" 
But here, I enter "vikash2" it's different. 
I want the exact match but cash insensitive.

Comment: Use collation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015712/mongodb-sort-with-case-insensitive-manner/52015956#52015956... `User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).collation({ locale: "en" })`

Comment: Also specify the strength option. `.collation({ locale: "en",strength: 2 })`

Comment: User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).collation({ locale: "en",strength: 2 }).select('_id').exec(function (err, user) { });
It's not working @ashh

Comment: No it is working I have tested it. Remove `select` and check again.

Comment: After remove select it's working thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).collation({ locale: "en", strength: 2 }).exec(function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({  "status": 0, "message": "Something went wrong" });
                } else {
                    if (user) {
                        res.json({ "status": 0, "message": "This username is already taken.", "data": user });
                    } else {
                        res.json({ "status": 1, "message": "Username is valid" });
                    }
                }
            });
```