# How to use rawCollection in a Meteor publish function

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish

I'm trying to use rawCollection in a Meteor 1.8.1 publish function, based on the example [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-subscribe-to-rawcollection/23959). Instead of returning the distinct values, I want to return a regular cursor containing all my documents. This is so I can later use collation to implement a [case-insensitive sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015712/mongodb-sort-with-case-insensitive-manner/52015956).

However when I subscribe to the publication below, I get the following error:

```
Publish function can only return a Cursor or an array of Cursors
```

But the console log in the server prints out the following:

```
result Cursor {
I20191107-11:44:26.485(0)?   pool: null,
I20191107-11:44:26.485(0)?   server: null,
I20191107-11:44:26.485(0)?   disconnectHandler: 
...
```

So, it appears that my code is producing a Cursor, but the publish function doesn't like it.

Here's my code:

publications.js:

```
const raw = MyCollection.rawCollection();
raw.findme = Meteor.wrapAsync(raw.find);

Meteor.publish('mycollection', function() {
    const result = raw.findme({});
    console.log('result', result);
    return result;
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: The native or raw collection is returning a native cursor. The publication should, however return a Mongo.Cursor, which is a custom cursor class in Meteor's mongo wrapper.

Comment: Is there a way for me to convert the native cursor to a Mongo.Cursor?

Comment: It's not documented because it was never intended but you should be able to review the Meteor Code on GitHub under packages -> mongo because Mongo.collection.find returns such a cursor. It should show you how to wrap it

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will do the job

```
Meteor.publish('mycollection', async function() {
    const result = await MyCollection.rawCollection().find({});
    console.log('result', result.fetch());
    return result;
});
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: I get this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: result.fetch is not a function. It looks to me as though your code is doing the same thing as mine, and is returning a native cursor not a Meteor cursor.